# If delete at indentation level

Tags: vim

I would like to implement this behaviour in insert mode:

**Before:**

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxx
    |[any string]
    xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**After: key press delete in insert mode**

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxx|[any string]
    xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

1. | = cursor
2. [any string] = "","text","[any-white-space]text"

How would you good sir implement this?

Comment: If you don't get anything useful here - try at http://vi.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Oh tnx, i would try it in vi.stack... but this is kinda programming question. :)

Comment: Sure, I never said it was off-topic here. But it'd probably also be on-topic there, and have a dedicated vi/vim-community.

Comment: Is it ok to share this ques. here and in vi/vim community ?

Comment: Nah, don't cross-post. But for any future questions you might have about vi/vim, you *can* direct them at vi.stackexchange.com. You don't have to. Just informing you of your possibilities. And, as always, please read the tour and about-pages for any community you wish to post questions in. =)

Comment: Ok tnx, I will considered for future question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that behavior by pressing `<C-U>` twice; once to delete the indent, once to join with the former line.

Now, you just need to check for the condition (cursor on a line with pure indent) and build a conditional mapping (cp. `:help :map-expression`):

```
:inoremap <expr> <BS> strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.') - 1) =~# '^\s\+$' ? '<C-u><C-u>' : '<BS>'
```

Comment: Uf now i remember 1 more thing, sorry, pls see the updated question :S.

Comment: The `=~#` is case-sensitive regular expression matching (against `^\s\+$`), cp. `:h =~#`

Comment: Oh cool i was aware for <==?>. I was thinking that this is some command in normal mode.

Comment: I will try to update your regex with updated question.

Comment: I've adapted to consider only the text _before_ the cursor.

Comment: Just give me a sec to test it. :)

Comment: Hands down, this is great answer! I will smile like a month because of that !:D